# Thrown exception "org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceLoadingException: Failed to open URL connection"

Tags: servlets, pentaho

How can I fix this error?

```
INFO  13-09 19:02:39,973 - Pentaho Reporting Engine Classic 3.8.3-GA.14625 started.
org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceLoadingException: Failed to open URL connection
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.loader.URLResourceData.getResourceAsStream(URLResourceData.java:128)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.loader.AbstractResourceData.getResource(AbstractResourceData.java:101)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.docbundle.bundleloader.ZipResourceBundleLoader.loadBundle(ZipResourceBundleLoader.java:81)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.DefaultResourceManagerBackend.loadResourceBundle(DefaultResourceManagerBackend.java:389)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.loadResourceBundle(ResourceManager.java:262)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.load(ResourceManager.java:284)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.create(ResourceManager.java:405)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.create(ResourceManager.java:370)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.createDirectly(ResourceManager.java:207)
    at com.C.doGet(C.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
ParentException:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\CHAKRI\Downloads\pre-classic-sdk-3.8.3-GA\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\qwer\chakri.prpt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.loader.URLResourceData.getResourceAsStream(URLResourceData.java:124)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.loader.AbstractResourceData.getResource(AbstractResourceData.java:101)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.docbundle.bundleloader.ZipResourceBundleLoader.loadBundle(ZipResourceBundleLoader.java:81)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.DefaultResourceManagerBackend.loadResourceBundle(DefaultResourceManagerBackend.java:389)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.loadResourceBundle(ResourceManager.java:262)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.load(ResourceManager.java:284)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.create(ResourceManager.java:405)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.create(ResourceManager.java:370)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.createDirectly(ResourceManager.java:207)
    at com.C.doGet(C.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your Pentaho template in the following path:
C:\Users\CHAKRI\Downloads\pre-classic-sdk-3.8.3-GA.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\qwer\chakri.prpt